# How do I mass assign attributes to model on google appengine / python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mass-assignment

I know I can use constructor to mass assign when creating the class:

```
attributes = {'name':'John', 'surname':'Smith', ...}
record = Model(**attributes)
```

but how can I assign the attributes when I have existing record?

```
record = ....
record.???(**attributes)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just assign to the attribute...

```
mymodel = MyModel()
mymodel.name = 'John'
mymodel.surname = 'Smith'
```

If you wanted to in effect do what the initialiser does, then you can use `setattr`

```
attributes = {'name':'John', 'surname':'Smith'}
record = Model()

for k, v in attributes.iteritems():
    setattr(record, k, v)
```

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model

and from there:

> An application creates a new data entity by instantiating a subclass
>   of the Model class. Properties of an entity can be assigned using
>   attributes of the instance, or as keyword arguments to the
>   constructor.

```
s = Story()
s.title = "The Three Little Pigs"

s = Story(title="The Three Little Pigs")
```